# How to pass text file from desktop C# app to Javascript web app

Tags: javascript, web-applications

I have a C# (unity) desktop app which regularly outputs a text file of player positions. I have a javascript web application that I would like to be able to read in this text file (or some other way of transferring the data) locally. I do not want to add the extra complexity and overhead of running a local server and I do not want to have to send the data over a network.

Is there some form of shared local storage that the C# application can write to that can be read by javascript run in a client's browser. I'm happy to get user permission on the first read, but it would not be practical to do so on every iteration (multiple times per second). Additionally, I would ideally like the website to work on most major browsers, so would prefer to avoid chrome-etc only solutions.

Comment: Running a local server should be an easy solution.

Comment: I might go with the local server if there is no other option but I'm concerned that the local server will add additional latency and potentially open up potential firewall problems on the client side, but perhaps that won't be as bad in practice.